# RestKit one-to-many relationship doesn't have the correct number of objects after mapping JSON response

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass `TAGRemoteObject`

**TAGRemoteObject.h**

```
extern const struct TAGRemoteObjectAttributes {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *object_Id;
} TAGRemoteObjectAttributes;

@interface TAGRemoteObject ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *object_Id;

@end
```

**TAGRemoteObject.m**

```
const struct TAGRemoteObjectAttributes TAGRemoteObjectAttributes = {
    .object_Id = @"object_Id",
};

@implementation TAGRemoteObject

@dynamic object_Id;

+(RKEntityMapping*)entityMappingInManagedObjectStore:(RKManagedObjectStore *)managedObjectStore
{
   RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

    [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"object_id" : TAGRemoteObjectAttributes.object_Id,
                                                        }];

    [entityMapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[ TAGRemoteObjectAttributes.object_Id ]];

    return entityMapping;
}

@end
```

Then I have two subclasses of `TAGRemoteObject`. `TAGPost` has a one-to-many `viewedUsers` relationship to `TAGUser`. `TAGUser` also has a one-to-many `posts` relationship to `TAGPost`.

**TAGPost.h**

```
extern const struct TAGPostRelationships {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *viewedUsers;
} TAGPostRelationships;

@interface TAGPost : TAGRemoteObject ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *viewedUsers;

@end
```

**TAGPost.m**

```
const struct TAGPostRelationships TAGPostRelationships = {
    .viewedUsers = @"viewedUsers",
};

@implementation TAGPost

@dynamic viewedUsers;

+(RKEntityMapping*)entityMappingInManagedObjectStore:(RKManagedObjectStore *)managedObjectStore
{
    RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [super entityMappingInManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

    RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [TAGUser entityMappingInManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

    RKRelationshipMapping *viewedUsersMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"viewed_users" toKeyPath:TAGJourneyOutgoingPostRelationships.viewedUsers withMapping:userMapping];
    viewedUsersMapping.assignmentPolicy = RKUnionAssignmentPolicy;
    [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:viewedUsersMapping];

    return entityMapping;
}

@end
```

**TAGUser.h**

```
extern const struct TAGUserAttributes {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *username;
} TAGUserAttributes;

extern const struct TAGUserRelationships {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *posts;
}

@interface TAGUser : TAGRemoteObject ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *posts;

@end
```

**TAGUser.m**

```
const struct TAGUserAttributes TAGUserAttributes = {
    .username = @"username",
};

const struct TAGUserRelationships TAGUserRelationships = {
    .posts = @"posts",
};

@implementation TAGUser

@dynamic username;
@dynamic posts;

+(RKEntityMapping*)entityMappingInManagedObjectStore:(RKManagedObjectStore *)managedObjectStore
{
    RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [super entityMappingInManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

    [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"username" : TAGUserAttributes.username,
                                                        }];

    RKEntityMapping *postEntityMapping = [TAGPost entityMappingInManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

    RKRelationshipMapping *postsRelationshipMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"posts" toKeyPath:TAGUserRelationships.posts withMapping:postEntityMapping];
    postsRelationshipMapping.assignmentPolicy = RKUnionAssignmentPolicy;
    [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:postsRelationshipMapping];

    return entityMapping;
}

@end
```

The issue I'm having is that when I receive a JSON response like this for the home feed which has many users, I get a `viewedUsers.count` of 3 which is expected:

```
{
    "error": null,
    "result": [
        {
            "object_id": 1,
            "username": "a",
            "posts": [
                {
                    "object_id": 299,
                    "viewed_users": [
                        {
                            "object_id": 3,
                            "username": "b"
                        },
                        {
                            "object_id": 4,
                            "username": "b"
                        },
                        {
                            "object_id": 5,
                            "username": "b"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I send a request for all the posts for user `1` and get the following response, `viewedUsers.count` is either 0 or 1 randomly for every post:

```
{
    "error": null,
    "result": [
        {
            "object_id": 299,
            "viewed_users": [
                {
                    "object_id": 3,
                    "username": "b"
                },
                {
                    "object_id": 4,
                    "username": "b"
                },
                {
                    "object_id": 5,
                    "username": "b"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "object_id": 300,
            "viewed_users": [
                {
                    "object_id": 3,
                    "username": "b"
                },
                {
                    "object_id": 4,
                    "username": "b"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "object_id": 301,
            "viewed_users": [
                {
                    "object_id": 3,
                    "username": "b"
                },
                {
                    "object_id": 4,
                    "username": "b"
                },
                {
                    "object_id": 5,
                    "username": "b"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I send the request to homefeed, I map to `[TAGUser entityMappingInManagedObjectStore:self.objectManager.managedObjectStore];`

When I send a request to get the posts for the user, I map to `[TAGPost entityMappingInManagedObjectStore:self.objectManager.managedObjectStore];`

I'm really lost as to why the mapping just doesn't work sometimes. When I set RestKit's logging level to `RKLogLevelTrace`, it sees the JSON array of length 3, but after mapping, the relationship only has 0 or 1.

**Edit:** I suspected that the circular relationship might be the issue, so I removed the `posts` relationship from the `TAGUser` mapping. I'm still seeing the issue though.

Comment: If `TAGRemoteObject` is just used for the common `id` then you should get rid of it, it's not helping you really and its making things a lot less efficient at runtime. Also, are your relationships bi-directional in your model? It doesn't look like it from the code. It looks like a multiplicity issue where the model and the received data don't match.

Comment: @Wain the `TAGRemoteObject` Class does more than just initialize, but I omitted a bunch of code for simplicity purposes. By model do you mean the classes or Core Data? I used Mogenerator to ensure that the Classes match the Core Data properly.

Comment: The core data model compared to the JSON look to differ in relationships, should be many to many. Also you would need to Union the relationships. Turning on trace logging will assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the relationship was set to one-to-many, when it should have been set to many-to-many.